# Constrain many views vertically to never cross a line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've a registration form with many inputs that has a margin of 8dp each. It also has a title, with 24dp marginBottom. In some conditions, there are inputs that must hide.

So I want that the first one, whatever it be, to have an specific 24dp margin from title, and 8dp margin from each other.

I want to solve this problem with ConstraintLayout. This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cho_card_document"
tools:background="#FF0000"
tools:ignore="SpUsage, RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="274dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cho_shape_round_white_background"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/cho_ticket_view"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    tools:text="Awesome Title Form"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    tools:text="Awesome Input 1"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/input2"
    tools:text="Awesome Input 2"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/input3"
    tools:text="Awesome Input 3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit: I've updated the layout with an actual implementation, and some Screenshots.

Before:

[image: 24dp Margin from title]

After hidden `input1`, I get `input2` too near from `title`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by doing two things:

- Rebalance how your vertical margins are assigned
- Create a vertical "chain" between your title and the three input views

Rebalancing the margins is easy. Change the `android:layout_marginTop="24dp"` on your `input1` view to use `8dp` instead (just like `input2` and `input3`), and add `android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"` to your `title` view. This way, no matter which of your input views are hidden/visible, there will always be a total of 24dp between the title and the first input.

Creating the chain is a little more complicated. Every view in the chain has to have both a top and bottom constraint. The first view in the chain should have its top constrained to the `cho_ticket_view`, the last view in the chain should have its bottom constrained to the `cho_ticket_view`, and everything else should be constrained (in both directions) to its neighbors.

Here's what that looks like (omitting other attributes for the sake of brevity):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input2"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/input2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input3"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/input3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"/>
```

Once you have these eight constraints in place, these four views are now a "chain". Chains can be configured by adding extra attributes to the "head" of the chain (the first view, i.e. `title` for you).

You will need these attributes on the `title` view:

```
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
```

Making the chain a "packed" chain means that it puts all the extra space outside of the chain (rather than between the views in the chain). Giving it a vertical bias of `0` means that all the extra space goes below the chain (rather than above).

Here's the full XML, combining all of the things mentioned above:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cho_card_document"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="#FF0000"
    tools:ignore="SpUsage, RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
        android:layout_width="274dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cho_shape_round_white_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        tools:text="Awesome Title Form"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input2"
        tools:text="Awesome Input 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input3"
        tools:text="Awesome Input 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cho_ticket_view"
        tools:text="Awesome Input 3"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Excelent, I should practice more with chains. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to put them together in a Contraintlayout. Then you constrain that layout to the bottom of the title form at your desired margin. Then when you hide the input 1, input 2 can at most move up and replace input 1's position but not move the overall layout. Hope this helps

Comment: I've added some screenshots and explained a little more. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Awesome Title Form"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title1"
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input1"
        android:text="Awesome Input 1"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/input1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input2"
        android:text="Awesome Input 2"
   />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/input2"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input3"
        android:text="Awesome Input 3"

 />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if this works, but I need to use ConstraintLayout without nesting layouts. I know that this layout will get more complex. thanks.